# Jax RS: multipart/form-data boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary gives 415 unsupported media type

Tags: java, rest, kendo-ui, jax-rs

I have kendo upload widget send an uploaded file as Post request to the server; where JAX-RS is meant to handle it.

Looking at the network tab of chrome; here's what I see in the request:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryARilQnC5oS7lnLVU
Request Payload

------WebKitFormBoundaryARilQnC5oS7lnLVU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="test_blah.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryARilQnC5oS7lnLVU--
```

on the server; here's how I've implemented the Post method

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  public void uploadFiles(@FormDataParam("files") List<InputStream> files) {

    System.out.println("Reached UploadFiles");

  }
```

I get an exception stating: `Unsupported Media Type (415)` on client side

and on server side:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream of content type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryARilQnC5oS7lnLVU
```

The kendo call looks like this:

```
<div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="UploadController">
            <input name="files"
                         id="files"
                         type="file"
                         kendo-upload="uploader"
                         k-select="onSelect"
                         k-async="{ saveUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/upload', autoUpload: true }"/>
</div>
```

Can any one give me pointers on

1. How to accept the multipart/form-data request for this?
2. What's causing the Jax Rs to give this error? Is it the
       `WebKitFormBoundary` bit? and How can I make the server side code
       deal with this?

Comment: I think your server side is giving the correct error, It doesn't know how to convert the form-data into list of org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream, Also shouldn't that be java.io.InputStream? Are you following any example?